# preventing /account.1111 routes in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am able to enter /account.111 or /profile.111 in my URL's.
Is it possible to prevent these routes to be accepted by a rails application?

Comment: COuld you clarify what you mean by "prevent"?

Comment: preventing the possibility to add integers to any route and just redirect to a 404 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `constraints` block on the top of `routes.rb`

```
#config/routes.rb   
constraints(EndingWithDigit) do 
 match '*path' => redirect('/404')
end
```

Now, create class `EndingWithDigit` on `lib/ending_with_digit.rb`

```
#lib/ending_with_digit.rb
class EndingWithDigit
 def self.matches?(request)
   path = request.fullpath 
   if path =~ /^\/[\w]+[.]{1}+[\d]+/
     true
   else
    false
  end
 end
end
```

Now, include it in `config/initializers/`

```
#config/initializers/constraints.rb
require "ending_with_digit.rb"
```

You can check the [Ruby Regex Expression](http://rubular.com/r/8jrdJ7S31c) to know which urls it will send to 404.

Comment: Seems like a bit of ugly solution but will accept for best answer given

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you pass the model id to a Rails route that doesn't take a param.

```
accounts_path(@model) vs account_path(@model)
```

If using resources

If not this in indicative, as a mistake you made creating your custom routes.

What happens I think is it will call to_params(@model) which basically gives the default slug of :id back. This id is actually passed in to the (.:format) selector so you end up with account.111 instead of accounts/111 or accounts/111/edit.

`get '/accounts/:id(.:format)' => "accounts#show", :as => "edit_account"`

should work if you call it as `edit_account_path(@account)`

However

`get '/account', => "accounts#show", :as => "account"`

if you called this as `account_path(@account)` would likely produce `/account.111`

Further more a likely reason is you've messed up pluralization.

Do you have

resource accounts
resource account

or

`resources accounts` <----- correct

You want to use the plural in both cases usually

### Edit

I see the issue: yes, the issue is it matching .111 as the format param.

Answer (score 1):

You may constraint format, this should work

```
get '/account', constraints: { format: 'html' }
```

but I'm still not sure what are you trying to achieve. Why would someone put number for format?

EDIT

you may put all routes in a constraint block, but I think it's not really smart or effective

```
constraints: { format: 'html' } do
  ...
end
```

Comment: spiders that try to request all kind of links, the idea is to make it throw the 404 not found instead of trying to deliver such a invalid request. This could work but having to specify this for each line in routes.rb would be a mess, is there no system wide option to use and prevent those integers?

Comment: I think you shoud try cutting it on server (ngnix, apache) then, but I am not able to help you out with this.
Don't think that's such a big deal though.